# @ModelAttribute is returning null values with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

After days of research I have trouble finding a solution for my controller methods. I have two controller methods that seem to be problematic. The savings method is saving null values. I have no clue how to bind the values, that are being typed into the field, to the list /all. One for creating values with input fields and another to save the input values and update a list /all. I want to get the values that I put into the fields of the form and have a updated list /all, with the new values. Note that I am only trying to save two of eleven attributes of the entire class. The class has double values and true/false. Those are being saved into db, except for the important String values. Thanks ahead for the help!

First method:

```
@GetMapping("/create")
    public String showCreateForm(Model model, Branch branch) {
        List<Branch> branches = new ArrayList<>();
        BranchCreationDto branchesForm = new BranchCreationDto(branches);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            // the input field
            branchesForm.addBranch(new Branch());
        }

        model.addAttribute("form", branchesForm);
        return "branches/create";
    }
```

This method is has one input field, where values of Branch can be set.

Second method:

```
@PostMapping("/saving")
public String saveBranches(@ModelAttribute BranchCreationDto form, Model   model, Branch branch) {

    // saves null but needs to be saving the values that are being typed into the field
    this.branchRepository.saveAll(form.getBranches());

    model.addAttribute("branches", branchRepository.findAll());

    return "redirect:/all";

}
```

This method appears to have the problem at

> this.branchRepository.saveAll(form.getBranches());

It is returning null values. I have already tried putting branch.getName(), branch.getType() into the parameter. This does not work.

With the method /all the programm is returning the list.

```
@GetMapping("/all")
public String showAll(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("branches", branchRepository.findAll());
    return "branches/all";
}
```

This is my wrapper class

```
    import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


public class BranchCreationDto {

@Autowired
private List<Branch> branches;

    public BranchCreationDto(List<Branch> branches) {
        this.branches = branches;

    }

    public BranchCreationDto() {

    }

    public void addBranch(Branch branch) {
        this.branches.add(branch);
    }

    public List<Branch> getBranches() {
        return branches;
    }

    public void setBranches(List<Branch> branches) {
      this.branches = branches;
    }

}
```

And this is the form

```
<body>

<!-- Save -->
<form action="#" th:action="@{saving}" th:object="${form}"
    method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" th:value="Save"> <input
            type="reset" id="resetButton" name="reset" th:value="Reset" />
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Branch</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="branch, itemStat : *{branches}">
                    <td><input th:field="*{branches[__${itemStat.index}__].branch}" /></td>
                    <td><input th:field="*{branches[__${itemStat.index}__].type}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong, value do not pass from controller to thymeleaf by this way. I'll give you one example.
Example:
Controller:

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
model.put("branches", branchRepository.findAll());
return model;
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<input id="branches" type="hidden" th:value="${branches}"/>
```

Now on your value is pass to id branches.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have changed the controllers. I've created a new page to input new values and also created a new controller to save those values to the list. I am trying to edit and update existing values of the list. My edit list works fine, when I call it up. I am using a newly configured save method. My problem is with <td><input type = "hidden" th:name="|branches[${itemStat.index}].id|" th:value="${branch.getId()}"/></td>. When I try to save the updated value, it gives me a new empty value in the list and does not change existing values of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the field as a hidden input and the thymeleaf will send your changes:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{branches}"/>
```